# Php Splitting a txt file by full stop

Tags: php, file, if-statement, foreach, explode

In my text file I have sentences like this:

word word word word word.
twoword word word word word.
threeword word word word word.
fourword word word word word.
fiveword word word word word.

I want to split the text file by full stop and have each sentence in a new text file . I know I have to use file_put_content and foreach statement but I am struggling with getting my head around it.
Any help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = "word word word word word. twoword word word word word. threeword word word word word. fourword word word word word. fiveword word word word word.";

$splitted_text = explode(".", $text);


for($i = 0; $i < count($splitted_text); $i++){
    file_put_contents("file_$i", $splitted_text[$i].'.');

    //to display a file just use echo file_get_contents($file_name) as such :
    echo "file $i :<br/>";
    echo file_get_contents("file_$i"); //note that you could echo $splitted_text[$i]
    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Comment: implode joins an array, do you mean explode?

Comment: thanks, how would I echo each line of the text files, would be for statement aswell

Comment: sorry what? didn't understand.

Comment: meaning how would display the newly created text files in php, if that makes any sense :~

Answer (score 3):

You could use [explode()](https://www.php.net/explode) to split the content via the full stop:

```
$text = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$sentences = explode('.', $text);

// do stuff with sentences array
```